# Why my splice or push its not working with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, push, angularjs-ng-repeat, splice

I am trying to do an update for an array and i have to splice first that element and then make a push. That list I am using it in a HTML file, where i am using an ng-repeat.

```
vm.editTemplate=function() {
    var selectedTemplate = localStorage.getItem("selectedTemplate");
    localStorage.removeItem("selectedTemplate");
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'EditTemplateCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'template',
        templateUrl: 'views/templatess/addTemplate.html',
        locals: {
            template:selectedTemplate
        }
    })
    .then(function() { },
        function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            console.log($scope.templatesArray);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.templatesArray.length; i++) {
            if (item.id == $scope.templatesArray[i].id) {
                $scope.templatesArray.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

in my HTML file i have this

```
<div class="hover" 
     ng-repeat="list in templatesArray"
     ng-click="temp.selectUser(list)"
     ng-class="{'active': temp.selectedRow.id == list.id}"
     style=" cursor:pointer;border-bottom:1px solid #fff; margin-bottom:0;" 
     layout-align="space-around center"
     layout="row">
    <span flex="5"></span>  
    <span id="{{list.id}}" flex="90" ng-click="temp.selectTemplate(list)">
        {{list.description}}
    </span>
    <span flex="5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your two `console.log()`s being called?

Comment: sorry i forgot to erase it, i was just testing the code

Comment: No, it's fine - I'm just wondering if it's being called. I ask because it looks like you have set it up as the error function. `.then(function success() {}, function failure() {})` is the form and you have an empty function followed by the function with code. Just wondering why you had to use the error function and whether it's actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's good to do a splice inside a loop on the same array.

Furthermore, as already mentioned here, you should assign the results of splice.

So I would rather do:

```
1. Find the index, something like following (or with the help of a 
library like underscore.js to avoir to write your own loop)

var index = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.templatesArray.length; i++) {
    if (item.id==$scope.templatesArray[i].id) {
       index = i;
    }
}

2. Then splice

if (index > -1) {
    $scope.templatesArray = $scope.templatesArray.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: when i check the info in a console log, i see that the splice has been donde, but my list in html file doesn't have changes

Comment: i solved it, jejeje the problem was that i was getting in the same controller 3 times, so in some point the conection with my html dissapear. something like that.